# php mysql login issue

Tags: php, mysql, authentication

```
<?
    include "conn.php";
    $username = $_POST["username"];
    $password = md5 ($_POST["password"]);

    $sql = "SELECT * FROM user where username='" . $username . "'
    and password='" . $password . "'";
    $result = mysql_query( $sql, $conn );
    $row=mysql_fetch_array($result);
    $count=mysql_num_rows($result);
    print_r($row);
    if(! $result ){
        die('Could not get data: ' . mysql_error());// se não funcionar dá erro
    }
    if ($count==1){
        if ($row['typeUser'] != 'cliente' || $row['typeUser'] != 'empregado' || $row['typeUser'] != 'admin'){
            if ($row['estadoUser'] == 'inactivo'){
                ?>
                    <SCRIPT LANGUAGE='JavaScript'>
                    window.alert('Utilizador bloqueado')
                    window.location.href='LoginForm.html;
                    </SCRIPT>
                <?
            }
            if ($row['typeUser'] == 'cliente' && $row['estadoUser'] == 'activo'){
                    session_register("username");
                    $_SESSION['login_user'] = $username;
                ?>
                    <SCRIPT LANGUAGE='JavaScript'>
                    window.alert('Succesfull')
                    window.location.href='homeCliente.php';
                    </SCRIPT>
                <?
                }

            if ($row['typeUser'] == 'admin' && $row['estadoUser'] == 'activo'){
                    session_register("username");
                    $_SESSION['login_user'] = $username;
                ?>
                    <SCRIPT LANGUAGE='JavaScript'>
                    window.alert('Succesfull')
                    window.location.href='homeAdmin.php';
                    </SCRIPT>
                <?          
            }
            if ($row['typeUser'] == 'empregado' && $row['estadoUser'] == 'activo'){
                    session_register("username");
                    $_SESSION['login_user'] = $username;
                ?>
                    <SCRIPT LANGUAGE='JavaScript'>
                    window.alert('Succesfull')
                    window.location.href='homeAdmin.php';
                    </SCRIPT>
                <?          
            }
        }
        else{
            ?>
                <SCRIPT LANGUAGE='JavaScript'>
                window.alert('Tipo de utilizador errado contacte o admin')
                window.location.href='LoginForm.html';
                </SCRIPT>
            <?      
        }
    }
    else{
        ?>
        <SCRIPT LANGUAGE='JavaScript'>
        window.alert('Wrong Username or Password')
        //window.location.href='LoginForm.html';
        </SCRIPT>
    <?
    }
    mysql_close($conn);
?>
```

My objective is when row[estadoUser] == inactivo i should be given the alert that the user is blocked and be redirected to loginform but instead i successfully login as cliente.

The code that is related to typeUser works fine. I can login with different usertypes

Also i know that i should be using pdo and the code should be more secure but this is just for schoolwork

Comment: So what if its for schoolwork? Start learning to be a good programmer and write in the right way! maybe if you would do that you wouldn't post a question here

Comment: I do recommend you to avoid using mixed languages in your code (e.g. Portuguese), in (commends, database tables, flags, variables, etc).

Comment: I don't see session_start() also your code is very insecure. Read about SQL Injection

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Code blindness probably: Take a break and look for typos in your code.
Small syntax errors are in your js

```html
<script type="text/javascript">
  alert('Utilizador bloqueado');
  window.location='LoginForm.html';
</script>
```